How to perform a sweep on multiple nodes in azureml
I have been trying to do distributed training on azureml while also using the Sweep functionality but every time I try to set the instance_count to more than 1 node, when I create the job it only creates 1 node. No matter what I change about the pipeline it always runs each trial on only 1 node instead of the 8 that I request. The cluster i'm running on has 30 nodes available and the pipeline works for distributed training when I dont use the sweep step. PytorchDistribution is all setup and present in the job but instance_count always shows 1 even though I set it to 8 in pipeline
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient, Input
from azure.ai.ml.dsl import pipeline
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes
from azure.ai.ml.sweep import Uniform, MedianStoppingPolicy

@pipeline(
    name="training_pipeline",
    display_name="Training Pipeline",
    experiment_name="test-pipeline",
    default_compute="my-cluster",
)
def training_pipeline(
    development_data: str,
    test_data: str,
    name: str,
    description: str
):
    preprocess = components["model_preprocess"]
    preprocess_node = preprocess(
        development_data=development_data,
        test_data=test_data,
        label_col="label",
        tokenizer_name="distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased"
    )

    train = components["model_train"]
    train_node = train(
        dataset=preprocess_node,
        model_name="distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased",
        task="token-classification",
        learning_rate=Uniform(min_value=5e-07, max_value=5e-03),
        weight_decay=Uniform(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0)
    )
    train_node.set_resources(
        instance_type="my-cluster",
        instance_count=8
    )

    sweep_node = train_node.sweep(
        sampling_algorithm="bayesian",
        primary_metric="eval_overall_f1",
        goal="maximize",
        max_total_trials=30,
        max_concurrent_trials=3,
        early_termination_policy=MedianStoppingPolicy(delay_evaluation=5, evaluation_interval=2),
        compute="my-cluster",
    )

    compress = components["model_compress"]
    compress_node = compress(
        model=sweep_node,
        tokenizer_name="distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased"
    )

    quantize = components["model_quantize"]
    quantize_node = quantize(
        compressed_model=compress_node
    )

    register = components["model_register"]
    register(
        model=quantize_node,
        name=name,
        description=description
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dev_input = Input(
        type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE, path="azureml:train_data:1"
    )
    test_input = Input(
        type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE, path="azureml:test_data:1"
    )
    pipeline_job = training_pipeline(
        development_data=dev_input,
        test_data=test_input,
        name="test-model",
        description="Model to test with"
    )

    mlclient.jobs.create_or_update(pipeline_job)

When I run this code it makes the pipeline and the sweep step runs fine but each trial will only have 1 instance
Only 1 instance_count
